# Unable to register demo application by using the DJISDK

Tags: android, dji-sdk

I followed the AndroidStudio Tutorial mentioned in this link for activating the DJI SDK on my Matrice 100.
Integrate SDK into Application - DJI Mobile SDK Documentation

However, I keep getting this error:
register sdk failed, check if network is available

Looking at the "adb logcat" gives me a detailed error:
[Error in detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMoiT.png)

```
The metadata received from server is invalid, please reconnect to the server and try.
```

Can anyone give me a hint to fix this problem please?

Comment: In case it helps, 
My package id is unique to my app and the package id/app key combination is registered in my account at developer.dji.com

Comment: I was able to make it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to do bug registration error:

1. Please make sure you have an account in developer page of DJI.
2. Please make sure you have created an Android app in your developer account.
3. Please make sure the package id you use there is correct (matches your android app package id) .
4. Please make sure your API_KEY is declared in Manifest file.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Solved it before the solution is posted. This is my solution too.